# jersey 2.x dependency injection

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, hk2

hi i am facing problem while moving the below code from jersey 1.x to jersey 2.x

```
@Provider
public class LocaleProvider
      extends AbstractHttpContextInjectable<Locale>
      implements InjectableProvider<Context, Type> {

    @Override
    public Injectable<E> getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, Context a, Type c) {
        if (c.equals(Locale.class)) {
            return this;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ComponentScope getScope() {
        return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public Locale getValue(HttpContext c) {
        final Locales locales = c.getRequest().getAcceptableLanguages();
        if (locales.isEmpty()) {
          return Locale.US;
        }
        return locales.get(0);
    }
}
```

I also understand that HK2 is available in Jersey 2.0, but I cannot seem to find docs that help with Jersey 2.0 integration.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use the `@Context` annotation, really all you need to do is implement a [`Factory<T>`](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Factory.html) parameterized by the type you want to inject. You can even inject other standard injectable objects into the `Factory`, for instance `HttpServletRequest`, `ContainerRequestContext`, `HttpHeaders` among others. For example, to match what's going on in your example above

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;

public class LocaleFactory implements Factory<Locale> {

    private final HttpHeaders headers;

    @Inject
    public LocaleFactory(HttpHeaders headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    @Override
    public Locale provide() {
        List<Locale> acceptableLanguges = headers.getAcceptableLanguages();

        if (acceptableLanguges.isEmpty()) {
            return Locale.US;
        }

        if ("*".equals(acceptableLanguges.get(0).toString())) {
            return Locale.US;
        }

        return acceptableLanguges.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(Locale t) { /* Do nothing */ }
}
```

Then you need to bind the factory. For example in your `ResourceConfig`. You can set the scope there, as in the `getScope()` in your example. There is currently support for `Singleton`, `RequestScoped` and `PerLookup` (which is default if not specified)

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public AppConfig() {
        packages("packages.to.scan");

        register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bindFactory(LocaleFactory.class).to(Locale.class)
                                         .in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you are using a web.xml, then you can create a `Feature` and register the `AbstractBinder` there, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29275727/2587435)

After this, you can just inject it

```
@GET
public Response getLocale(@Context Locale locale) {
```

If you want to use a custom annotation, then you will need to implement an [`InjectionResolver`](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/InjectionResolver.html) for the custom annotation. You can see a complete example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022938/2587435), and read more in the [Jersey documentation - Defining Custom Injection Annotation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html#d0e16655)

Comment: it is not able to autowired the headers bean in the above code

Comment: What makes you say that? I've tested the above code before posting. I used Jersey 2.17 (the latest) to test. Did you do anything different from the above code?

Comment: actually i am using dropwizard 0.8.1 version

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. Did you `env.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder(){...});`?

Comment: yes i have done
 env.jersey().getResourceConfig().register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bindFactory(LocaleFactory.class).to(Locale.class)
                                         .in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });

Comment: Are you getting a NPE? Let me test it. Actually I'l test in a bit. but first can you try to use `javax.inject.Provider<HttpHeaders> headers`. Then when you retrieve it use `headers.get()` to get the actual `HttpHeaders`

Comment: i am not getting any error while building the code .. it was coming on intellij .. thanks :)

Comment: I don't know It works fine for me the first way without `Provider` (I thought it might be a scope issue). What makes you say it is not working?

Comment: no it is working with the first way only .. intellij was showing the error . but it was building fine.

Comment: its not working .. while i am hitting the request its not coming to provide methold.

Comment: And what if I want to inject it to a field like this?
`@Context
protected HttpServletRequest               request;`

Comment: @Phosphoros what's stopping you? You can post another question if something is not working for you

Comment: I need my resource to not be a singleton, because I have to pass objects for the constructor. So I can't register with `jersey.register(ResourceName.class);` and I don't know how to satisfy the request scope and the objects I have to pass for instantiation.
I followed the more detailed example here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629282/dropwizard-jersey-not-inside-a-request-scope-when-creating-custom-annotati?lq=1

Comment: @Phosphoros You can inject it as `javax.inject.Provider<Local>` and just call `get()` to lazily retrieve it on each request. Or you can make bind the `Factory` as proxiable.

Comment: @Phosphoros would you mind posting another question. There's more I can elaborate on this, but I'd rather not do it in comments