# Jersey - Inject variable from filter as RequestScoped

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I want to perform authentication in a filter before my resource method is called. Within this filter I would also like to retrieve the permissions of a user and pass it on through a RequestScoped @Inject annotation.

```
@Authenticated
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @NameBinding
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Authenticated {};

    @Inject
    private ISecurityHandler handler;

    public AuthenticationFilter() {}

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {    

        // Filter out unauthorized

        // Retrieve user permissions
        this.handler.setUserPermissions(...);
    }
}
```

Resource:

```
@Path("my-path")
public class GetVisitorsDataResource {

    @Inject private ISecurityHandler handler;

    @GET
    @Path("resource-method")
    @Authenticated
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response resource() {

        System.out.println(handler.getUserPermissions());

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

I have registered the filter and a Factory for the injection.

```
public static class SecurityHandlerProvider implements Factory<ISecurityHandler> {

    @Override
    public ISecurityHandler provide() {
        System.out.println("PROVIDING SECURITY CONTEXT!");
        return new SecurityHandlerImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(ISecurityHandler instance) {
        System.out.println("DISPOSING SECURITY CONTEXT!");
    }
}
```

I have also bound it.

```
bindFactory(SecurityHandlerProvider.class).to(ISecurityHandler.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
```

It is important that the object is created when a request is received and only accessible within that request. When the request is finished, the dispose method should be called. The only way I can achieve something similar is through the @Singleton annotation. However, the object is not destroyed after the request is completed and is shared across all requests.

I have been investing too much time into this issue already, is there perhaps anybody that knows how to achieve the preferred result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't really make much sense. One place you are injecting `ISecurityHandler`, and another place `SecurityHandler`, but the factory is for `ISecurityContext`. I will just assume those are typos or copy and paste errors.

Aside from that I'll assume that really all is ok, since you you said it works as a singleton. So I'm guessing you are facing the *"Not inside a request scope"* error. The easiest fix for that is to just inject using [`javax.inject.Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html), which allows us to lazily retrieve the object. When the object is retrieve, it will be withing a request scope.

```
@Inject
private javax.inject.Provider<ISecurityContext> securityContextProvider;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
    ISecurityContext sc = securityContextProvider.get();
}

...
bindFactory(SecurityHandlerProvider.class)
          .to(ISecurityContext.class)
          .in(RequestScoped.class);
```

NB, you should also make sure to annotate you `AuthenticationFilter` with `@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)` so that it occurs before any other filter even you my prefer it to be a `@PreMatching` filter. The earlier into the system the authentication happens, the better, I'd say.

As an aside, you may want to look into Jersey's [`RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e12228). It allows you to use the jsr250 annotations `@RolesAllowed`, `@DenyAll`, and `@PermitAll` for your resource classes and methods.

It is basically a filter that occurs after your `Priorites.AUTHENTICATION` filter, and it looks up the `javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext` from the `ContainerRequestContext` to look up roles. You just need to create the `SecurityContext` inside your authentication filter, so the next filter can look it up.

You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29768074/2587435). You can check the user permission in the `isUserInRole`. When the set the `SecurityContext`, Jersey's filter will be called afterwards, and it calls your `isUserInRole`. Doing it this way, you get access control for free.